# Add the elements to an array by clicking in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I want to create an array by clicking on the div element. Div it's a card of the product.

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      likesArr: []
    }
  }

  // toggle for changing
  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //toggle div to the favorite 
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { liked: !prevState.liked }
    })

    //creating an array
    let likesArr = this.state.likesArr;

    let newLike = e.currentTarget.id; // get product's id

    likesArr.push(newLike);

    // option 1
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      likesArr: [...previousState.likesArr, newLike]
    }));
    
    // option 2
    // this.setState({
    //   likesArr:[...this.state.likesArr,  newLike]
    // });
    console.log(likesArr);
  }

 return (
  ...
  <div className="liked" onClick={this.handleClick} id={product.id}>
   {product}
  </div>
  ...
)}
```

So the problem is I get only empty array with the last product's id
`["577922"]`, if I set initial array ["1"], I get `(2) ["1", "577922"]`, but not the new array...

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
Added  [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-smoke-nuoho?file=/src/Product.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    //creating an array
    let likesArr = this.state.likesArr;

    /* ... */

    likesArr.push(newLike);
```

This is wrong. You are taking the reference to the array in the state and mutate it.

You need to clone the array first. You can use `slice()` to achieve this:

```js
    let newLike = e.currentTarget.id; // get product's id

    this.setState(previousState => {
        let newLikesArr = previousState.likesArr.slice(); // <------------ THIS
        newLikesArr.push(newLike);

        return {
          likesArr: newLikesArr
        }
    });
```

Alternatively:

```js
    let newLike = e.currentTarget.id; // get product's id

    // Remove the other lines between those two

    // option 1
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      likesArr: [...previousState.likesArr, newLike]
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but both your options give the same result as I had.

Comment: Can you create a codepen with your code so I can take a look ?

Comment: What is likesArr supposed to contain ? The list of all the liked products ? In that case, it shouldn't be in Product, but in App's state.